# apply max function to numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Good morning!
I have an `np.array (1.1,2.2,3.3)`, and i want to pass the `array` to a simple `ma`x function, `max(0,(x-1.5)**3)` and I expect return of an `np.array (0,0.343,5.832)` 
I tried the follow code and received error.

```py
aaa = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
max(0, (aaa-1.5)**3)
```

How can I get the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `max()` (which knows little about NumPy objects) with either [`numpy.maximum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) or [`numpy.fmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html).
Both work similarly: they compare two arrays element-wise outputing the maximum, broadcasting inputs with different shapes.
They only differ in the way they treat NaNs: propagated with `np.maximum()` and ignored as much as possible with `np.fmax()`.

In your example, the `0` gets broadcasted to the shape of `aaa`:

```
import numpy as np

aaa = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
np.fmax(0, (aaa - 1.5) ** 3)
# array([0.   , 0.343, 5.832])
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using a list comprehension, therefore a for loop. You can apply your function with vectorization, create an array of zeros. Take the max of them :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1.1,2.2,3.3))
b = np.zeros(len(a))
np.maximum((a-1.5)**3,b)
```

Output :

```
array([0.   , 0.343, 5.832])
```

Comment: You don't need an array for `b`. NumPy broadcasting lets you just use a scalar 0. The important part is using `numpy.maximum` instead of the built-in `max`.

Answer (score -2):

```py
x = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
y = np.array(list(map(lambda t: max(0, (t - 1.5)**3), x)))
```